# onError event doesn't behave as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, reactjs

I have a very strange situation and can't somehow manage to solve it.

```
const handleImageError = e => {
    e.target.onerror = null;
    e.target.src = 'factory2.svg';
    e.target.width = 45;
    e.target.height = 41;
};

items.map(item => {
   if(item.data) {
       <img src={`${item.data}?size=20`} onError={handleImageError} />
   } else {
       <Logo styleName="defaultIconLogo" width={25} height={20} />
   }

})
```

I am handling image errors with the above function and give an image another source (factory.svg) and dimensions in case of error. I have a situation where the image loads and also have width and height given from the errorHandler.
I think it fails to load the image first time, then onError triggers and changes the  dimensions, and in the end, it loads successfully. If it loads in the end, then I don't want to have width and height on image.
The src example is **https://logo.clearbit.com/op.fi?size=20**.
The problem is that when it loads the image from an incoming source, it has his dimensions already binded , but when errorHandler triggers , it overrides the image dimensions and gives them `width='45'` and `height='41'` . I only need this dimensions to be given to image when the source URL doesn't work

Comment: whats your issue?

Comment: See updated version

Comment: handleError always trigger even if the image present?

Comment: No ... It triggers only when the source URL doesn't work

Comment: width="45" height="41" get applied for success url?
i dont feel any issue in your code

Comment: Yes , but it shouldn't, because if URL is valid and no errors , the image onError shouldn't be triggered

Comment: So set/remove the width and height with load

Answer (score 0):

Once again verify your code i think some of the things missed in your code

```
const handleImageError = e => {
    e.target.onerror = null;
    e.target.src = 'factory2.svg';
    e.target.width = 45;
    e.target.height = 41;
};

items.map(item => {
   if(item.data) {
// the image source is like path of the image right here you are assigning size value  
       <img src={`${item.data}?size=20`} onError={handleImageError} />
//here your are using conditional statement right where you close properly the conditional statement should be like condition==true?true:false
   } else {
       <Logo styleName="defaultIconLogo" width={25} height={20} />
   }

})
```